# How can I perform this in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008, I have something similar to this:

`Accounts`:

```
aaa | 01/01/2010 | 15.00    
bbb | 01/01/2010 | 20.00  
ccc | 01/01/2010 | 10.00    
ddd | 02/01/2010 | 30.00   
eee | 04/01/2010 | 25.00  
fff | 05/01/2010 | 1.00
```

`Transactions`:

```
aaa | 01/01/2010 | 15.00      
aaa | 02/01/2010 | 20.00     
aaa | 03/01/2010 | 5.00    
bbb | 01/01/2010 | 15.00   
bbb | 04/01/2010 | 5.00  
ccc | 04/01/2010 | 10.00      
ddd | 05/01/2010 | 25.00
```

I need the results to be something like:

```
      Jan-10    Feb-10  Mar-10  Apr-10  May-10  Accts tot   Trans Tot
Jan-10  15      20      5       5       0       45          45
Feb-10  15      0       0       15      0       30          30
Mar-10  0       0       0       0       0       0           0
Apr-10  0       0       0       0       0       25          25
May-10  0       0       0       0       0       0           0
```

I hope that makes sense... Each cell is the sum of the transactions for accounts created in a certain month. So accounts created in January will have a transaction total each month for the year. The first column is the account date, the row is the transaction date, and the cells are sums anytime an account created in that month has a transaction in the corresponding month.

Right now I do a join on the tables, then loop through and calculate each cell.

The loop is killing my processing time.

Comment: Can you add your current query to the question?

Comment: Can you add some sample data to the question?  It sound like you might be able to pivot this, but it'd be easier to see some sample data along with the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you'll find a query to return that. Many years ago I was an expert in sqlServer but I've forgot many things about transact-sql, what I did when I had those kind of problems was to create a temporary table with the columns needed based on a query and start inserting the information, using cursors to loop the information. At the end just a "select * from #temp". Hope this idea helps...

Comment: The more I look at the problem at hand, the more I think setting up a second table is the most practical solution - the data rarely changes.